# Is there a tool to automatically minify all javascript files referenced in an html file at deployment time?

Tags: javascript, html, deployment, minify

Is there a tool that will do the following at deployment time?

1. Find all javascript files referenced in `<script>` tags of an html document.
2. Minify the javascript files into 1 file.
3. Replace the `<script>` tags in the html file with just one that points to the minified file.

I can't be the only one wanting to do this, so just before I write a tool myself, is there already a utility that does this?

I'm using Go on Google App Engine.

Comment: Google closure compiler (http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) offers an API you could integrate into your deployment process

Answer (score 3):

What's your server side technology? If it's ASP.NET, look at http://www.RequestReduce.com. It will bundle and minify all `<script>` and `<link rel="stylesheet>` tags among other optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to describe what code stack you are using, i.e. LAMP, Java EE....

For PHP this looks tempting:
http://code.google.com/p/minify/

Answer (score 0):

You could use build tools such as [Makefile](https://gist.github.com/659427) or [Ant](http://vegdave.wordpress.com/2008/10/20/using-minify-ant-target/)